# How to make a iframe Autoscroll when loaded

Tags: php, html, iframe, autoscroll

Hey guys so i have this PHP page and 1 iframe code at the top of the page when you scroll down theres links and when clicked it loads in that iframe uptop what im trying to figure out how to do is  when the link is clicked it Auto scrolls back to the top of the page so oyu can see the new iframe. `<font color="#5185C9"><b>Watch</b></font>Video name <a href="linktovideo" target="Videoframe">LOAD VIDEO NOW</a><br/>` so my goal is when they click LOAD VIDEO NOW it scrolls to the top of the page and displays that video in the iframe i have placed up top. Any help with this would be awesome! or even any advice! thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="linktovideo" 
target="Videoframe" 
onclick="window.scrollTo(top);" >LOAD VIDEO NOW</a>
```

Comment: Yes!!!! omg you are amazing i tried hours to try to get this working lol!